# Get column of a mysql entry

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Is there a possibility to get the name of the column a database entry belongs to?

Perhaps I have three columns with column names col1, col2 and col3. Now I want to select for every column the column with the maximum entry, something like this.

`Select name_of_column(max(col1,col2,col3))`.

I know that I can ask for the name of the columns by its ordinal position in the information_schema.COLUMNS table but how do I get the ordinal position of a database entry within a table?

Comment: what is an `entry`? A column? a column's value? RowID?

Comment: no an entry in a table, perhaps the entry of column 1 in the third row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement it in a pure SQL, you can use CASE statement and an additional variable:

```
 SELECT @m := GREATEST(col1, col2), 
 CASE @m 
      WHEN col1 THEN 'col1' 
      WHEN col2 THEN 'col2' 
 END 
 FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show you the columns from a table

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM 'table';
```

You'll then have to iterate through the results in a scripting language.

Comment: thanks for this but isn't there any other way to get the column name for an entry without using a scripting language?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
select
    case true
        when col1 > col2 and col1 > col3 then 'col1'
        when col2 > col1 and col2 > col3 then 'col2'
        when col3 > col1 and col3 > col2 then 'col3'
    end 
from
    mytable
```

But what if the maximum value appears in multiple columns?

Comment: good argument but in my special case it is very unlikely to happen